# compare the files and display the names present in each one

Tags: awk

I have four files and need to print the IDs which are in all files. I tried the following code for two files. How should I proceed with four files?

Also need to print the IDs which are NOT in all files.

`awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next } $1 in a' file2 file1`

```
file1
ID_1
ID_3
ID_4

file2
ID_3
ID_2
ID_4 

file3
ID_6
ID_3
ID_4
```

Desired output (IDs present in all files)

```
ID_3
ID_4
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your code. Could you please do post all sample files in your question also so that we can relate it also mention samples of output in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If all IDs can appear at most once per file:

```
sort file1 file2 file3 file4 |
uniq -c |
awk '{ print $2 > ( $1==4 ? "in-all" : "not-in-all" ) }'
```

If any ID can appear more than once in a single file:

```
find file1 file2 file3 file4 -exec sort -u {} \; |
sort |
uniq -c |
awk '{ print $2 > ( $1==4 ? "in-all" : "not-in-all" ) }'
```

Replace output filenames with something appropriate.

It is not completely trivial to extend the pure awk version if an ID can appear more than once in a single file. If they can appear at most once:

```
awk '
    { a[$1]++ }
    END {
        n = ARGC-1
        for (i in a)
            print i > (a[i]==n ? "in-all" : "not-in-all")
    }
' file1 file2 file3 file4
```

Comment: @jhnc regarding your 2nd code, observe that using `$1` will get 1st column value, that is all before 1st whitespace character, as hsa does not provide guarantee that every line has exactly 1st line consider using `$0` instead

Comment: @Daweo I just adapted the code from the question which uses `$1`. If anything, it is my first code that is questionable as it assumes that whitespace is significant.